# Bash: Detect all disks and show the free space

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, freebsd

I'm running the following command to get the available space on my HHD. In this case I know the device (/dev/disk0s2).

I'm wondering how to first detect all the HDD's and then run the df command below to show the available disk space of all HDD's.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2   112Gi   58Gi   54Gi    52%    /
/dev/disk0s3   800Gi   400Gi  400Gi   50%    /

 df -h | awk '$1=="/dev/disk0s2"{print $4}'
```

Result: 54Gi

Result I need: disk0s2: 54Gi, disk0s3: 400Gi, etc....

Comment: Below is the answer I was looking for an it was useful to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
df -h | tail -n+2 | while read fs size used rest ; do
    if [[ $used ]] ; then
        echo $fs $used
    fi
done
```